# simple implementation of a TCP client server relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp

I have a simple implementation of a TCP client server relationship. But their are few problems that i don't know how to fix. here is the code of the Client and Server:
Client and Server are both separated. Each one of them is written i different project.

```
  public void Server()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IP, 8001);               
            Listener.Start();

            Socket s = Listener.AcceptSocket();

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
                 ConsoleWpfGUI.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string:"+strTemp+ " was recieved by the server."));

            s.Close();
            Listener.Stop();

        }
       catch (Exception e) {
              ConsoleWpfGUI.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
             }    
       }   
   }

public void Client()
    {

        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

            tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);

            String str = InputString.Text;
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
              ConsoleWpfGUI.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ConsoleWpfGUI.Text = "No connection..... ";
        }
      }
   }
```

1. The listener does not work properly, i.e. the listening captures the GUI thread (serv and client classes that i use in wpf). and not running in a separate thread, resulting with  the application being unresponsive once “listen” (Buttoon that start the class serv) is pressed.

2. Only with the 1st call being replied it's work,the next send is fails. resulting not dealing with the socketing and passing to a separate thread right on the server side.

How can I use Thread that the serv class will not stuck the app.
And how i can use properly with socketing and passing threads that will make my app work more then ones.

Thanks!

Comment: One of the easiest way - use backgroundworker.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use separate threads for "Client" and "Server". You cannot run both in one UI thread. Because listening will block your UI thread and hence neither Client or Server can run correctly.

You can find many resources over internet about Client Server practice examples. Just use Threading, Background Workers for accomplish your task

Good Articles :
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607801/SimpleplusChatplusprogramplusinplusC , 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

I ran your code. Try running following on TWO Console programs - Rub them Separately and run Server first

Client -

```
         try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

            tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);

            String str = "From CLient";
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No connection..... ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Transmission end.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Server -

```
        string strTemp = "Hello from server";

        try
        {
            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IP, 8001);
            Listener.Start();

            Socket s = Listener.AcceptSocket();

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string:" + strTemp + " was recieved by the server."));

            s.Close();
            Listener.Stop();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Note - Just paste them inside Main method and try, you will need Sytem.IO import in Visual Studio ()

Comment: Hey Client and Server are both separated. Each one of them is written i different project.

Comment: Yes you can use two different projects for this if you like but I suggest to go simple first.

Write two console applications , one acting as client other acting as server. Both communicating with same port address. Since you have two console applications you will not need Threading [But two terminals to run them separately], just use while loops.. Go through examples I provided and once you understood them go for threading.

Comment: This is exactly what i already did. But the Server app form is freezed while he listening.

Comment: Run your Server first then run Client.. Check you are listening and sending to same port.

Form will freeze because listening blocks UI thread. I suggest you to start with Console applications which is easier to handle.

Comment: Yes i did it. I sendidng to same Port.

Comment: Try Updated Suggestions.. Use Console programs and start practicing rather than using GUI

Comment: I ran it. Two programs separetly in wpf. still the UI is freezed.